# Code highlighting on a sharepoint blog premises/online

Tags: 2013

I am evaluating to change my wordpress blog for a sharepoint blog either online or on premises.

The only thing I need to be sure I can make it work, is code highlighting.

How can I do that?

Something like this:
https://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

Comment: This is good solution : check this out http://yasingokhanyuksel.blogspot.com.tr/2017/07/sharepoint-code-syntax-highlighting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here, I think this should be enough
http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/04/how-to-integrate-syntax-highlighter-with-sharepoint.html

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)